# Extracting Nouns and Entities using Regex and POS

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I am no expert in python, I am just trying few algorithms.

I have a sentence, for example,

```
"The maker of Sam Global Ent, Sam Helsen has bought many stocks in a private intelligence firm Samligence."
```

I am trying to get all the nouns using a POS-tagger, however, if succeding entities starts with a capital letter they should be considered as one entity.

For Example :  "Sam Global Ent" should be considered as one entity.

The output I am looking for is given below:

```
[u'maker',                     --  Noun
 u'Sam Global Ent',            --  Considered as one entity
 u'Sam Helsen',                --  Considered as one entity
 u'stocks',                    --  Noun
 u'intelligence',              --  Noun
 u'firm',                      --  Noun 
 u'Samligence']                --  Noun/entity
```

I've written code to do both the job seperately, But I have no idea how to combine them in a performance efficient way.

The code that I've written so far is ..

## For Extrating the succeding entities starting with a capital letter:

```
find_entities=re.findall(r'\b[A-Z]\w+(?:\s\b[A-Z]\w+)*', sentences, re.DOTALL)
```

Output:

```
find_entities= ['The', 'Sam Global Ent', 'Sam Helsen', 'Samligence']
```

## For Extracting all the nouns:

```
words=word_tokenize(sentences.decode('utf-8'))
    for pos in pos_tag(words):
        if 'NN' in pos[1]:
            entity_nouns.append(pos[0])
```

Output:

```
 entity_nouns=
[u'maker',
 u'Sam',
 u'Global',
 u'Ent',
 u'Sam',
 u'Helsen',
 u'stocks',
 u'intelligence',
 u'firm',
 u'Samligence']
```

I've thought of approaches like intersection. For example breaking the "find_entities" into single elements (['The', 'Sam', 'Global', 'Ent', 'Sam', 'Helsen', 'Samligence']), then subtracting it to entity_nouns and then adding the resultant to find_entities again. But this seems a very long process.

I'd be glad if anybody could help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your tried [TextBlob](https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob)? it extracts the noun phrases:

```
>>> from textblob import TextBlob
>>> txt = """The maker of Sam Global Ent, Sam Helsen has bought many stocks in a private intelligence firm Samligence."""
>>> blob = TextBlob(txt)
>>> blob.noun_phrases
WordList([u'sam global ent', u'sam helsen', u'private intelligence firm', 'samligence'])
```

Comment: Thanks, this really helped.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a simple approach: you're already tokenizing the sentence into words. Instead of the regex approach to find the entities, just do one iteration over your word list and combine consecutive words of the list that start with uppercase letters.

Comment: Gotcha, but would that be fast enough? Normally predefined function like "regex", "intersection (using sets)", "union" and other are fast compared to approaches that includes traversing through each word.

Comment: I think that's hard to compare without actually measuring it. Regexes don't come for free either. Anyway, unless you expect the list-iteration to perform _ridiculously_ bad, I would consider this as "premature optimization".